# How to use OrdinalEncoder() to set custom order?

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-engineering

I have a column in my Used cars price prediction dataset named "Owner_Type". It has four unique values which are ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']. Now the order that makes the most sense is First > Second > Third > Fourth as the price decreases with respect to this order. How can I give this order to the values with OrdinalEncoder()? Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) has a `categories` parameter which accepts a list of arrays of categories. Here is a code example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['first','second','third','forth']])
X = [['third'], ['second'], ['first']]
enc.fit(X)
print(enc.transform([['second'], ['first'], ['third'],['forth']]))
```

Comment: Why do you have to fit the encoder to X if you are already supplying the categories?

Comment: if you apply transform without applying fit you get an error "AttributeError: 'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute 'categories_'" so you must aplly fit_transform or fit the model first and then apply transform.

Comment: I see, you're totally right. It's a bit silly, though, since the calling fit when the categories are already supplied does nothing other than create the attribute `categories_`. It seems that this attribute should be created automatically if categories are supplied.